# WooCommerce Image Size

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

In the Shop Page, or when I use this:

```
[featured_products per_page="4" columns="4" orderby="date" order="ASC"]
```

or This:

```
[best_selling_products per_page="4" columns="4"]
```

I see images in diferent sizes, please see example image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9506723/zapatos_grandes.jpg

How I can do to force to show all the images in the same size (using code in the style file) ?.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: This issue has to do with the image proportions, and WordPress's ability to crop/resize images that are taller than they are wide. It's definitely not a WooCommerce issue. I would make sure your images are the correct dimensions, and that you have "hard cropping" enabled.

Comment: Hi rneius: Thanks for your answer. It´s enabled.
I need something like that:

.product-category .product-image-wrapper img {
height: 100px! important;
width: auto;
}

I used this code to show all the images category:

 [product_categories orderby="name" order="ASC" columns="4" ids="16,17,14,15,18,22,24,25,29,30,23"]

In the same size.

Now I need to show in the same size the results of the others Woocommerce Shortcodes: featured_products and best_selling_products.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I had three pages where i was calling products using shortcodes. I used developer tools in chrome (option + cmd + i) on a mac, to determine the right classes to target and modify the size.

```
.page-id-339 .woocommerce ul.products li.product,
.page-id-339 .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product 
{
width: 100%!important;
}

.page-id-3300 .woocommerce ul.products li.product,
.page-id-3300 .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product
{
width: 100%!important;
}

.page-id-16 .woocommerce ul.products li.product,
.page-id-16 .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product
{
width: 100%!important;
}
```

The key here is i used the post id for the page to ensure only the image size of the products on that page is used. You could probably remove the post id and use the rest of the css selector classes to target all the images.

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product,
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product
{
width: 100%!important;
}
```

Make sure you put !important.

Comment: Hi MythRaven , first off all, thank you for your time.

I tried the two codes, making the necessary changes in the first, and in either case it worked.

Any other ideas?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think you mean it didn't work. Did you try: `.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product { height: 100px! important; width: auto; }`

Comment: If that doesnt work, i highly advise loading the page in question in chrome, then using developer tools to inspect the element that is bigger. [link] (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/tips-and-tricks#inspect-element-line) this site gives you quick tutorial how. You can then add css class to the element to see live changes to determine what works. Then all you have to do is copy the added css to your style.css file.

Comment: Hi MythRaven

This exceeds my abilities, if you could please help me further, I would be very grateful. Anyway, thank you very much to you.